# SpringData regex not working as expected

Tags: regex, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Working native query

```
{
  $match: {
    $and : [
      {userType:"200"},
      {
        $or: [
          {login     : /infosys/},
          {email     : /infosys/},
          {firstName : /infosys/},
          {lastName  : /infosys/}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

SpringData API which is not working as expected:

```
match(
    Criteria.where("userType").is(userType).orOperator(
        Criteria.where("login").regex(searchTxt).orOperator(
            Criteria.where("email").regex(searchTxt).orOperator(
                Criteria.where("firstName").regex(searchTxt).orOperator(Criteria.where("lastName").regex(searchTxt))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: what are you passing as searchText for this regex? `/infosys/` or `infosys`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are $or each criteria with the `$or` operator. `orOperator` takes a list of crtieria.

Below is the equivalent for your native query.

```
match
(
  Criteria.where("userType").is(userType)
  .orOperator(
      Criteria.where("login").regex(searchTxt), 
      Criteria.where("email").regex(searchTxt), 
      Criteria.where("firstName").regex(searchTxt), 
      Criteria.where("lastName").regex(searchTxt)
    )
)
```

Comment: The following native query fetches one record

Comment: working query                                        
 { $match: {$and : [{userType:"200"},{$or: [ {login:/suresh/},{email:/suresh/},{firstName:/suresh/},{lastName:/suresh/}]}]} },    
 Equivalent Spring data - no records                                                match
 (
       Criteria.where("userType").is(userType)
       .orOperator(
           Criteria.where("login").regex(searchTxt), 
           Criteria.where("email").regex(searchTxt), 
           Criteria.where("firstName").regex(searchTxt), 
           Criteria.where("lastName").regex(searchTxt)
         )
     ),

Comment: What is your searchTxt value ? Can you show the document native query returns ?

Comment: My searchTxt is "suresh" for both native and Springdata query. Following is the native query returns { "_id" : "259490257", "login" : "ms349j", "firstName" : "Malathy", "lastName" : "Suresh", "createdOn" : "2017-04-12 00:30:46.271", "email" : "malathy.suresh@abc.com", "deactivateFlag" : false, "c
reatedBy" : [ { "name" : "Ravichandran" } ] }

Comment: I don't see any userType in your document. may be that is the reason the spring query is not working. The query works for me if I don't include the userType in the match stage.

Comment: It is working. I am using skip and limit for pagination at front end. Just realized that I am passing skip as zero instead of one.